# Display Calculated Column on New/Edit Forms

Tags: 2013

I have a list with some calculated columns in it and I would like to know how to display them on the New/Edit form without Sharepoint Designer. My organization has upgraded to SharePoint 2013 but has not Upgraded SharePoint Designer, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the calculated field is not shown in new and edit form it's visible on the display form or in views. where it is calculated after the item added or updated.

Meanwhile and based on your calculated field formula, if you are using SharePoint Enterprise edition, you can achieve that via InfoPath by

- Editing the list form with InfoPath from the list ribbon.

[image]

- And insert a calculated field value.

[image]

- And insert a formula that will do the same calculation of your calculated field.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think that I figured it out with your suggestion of using InfoPath

Answer (score 0):

You can develope a custom HTML plus Javascript/Jquery to do the job. I have a large experience with infopath and can tell you that as more complex your form grows it is hard to manage rules. Give a try using javascript and custom form webpart. It is so easy that you can write your code in the page and can call Javascript CSOM from page. Tell me if you need to see some example.